# NSIS recursive file log

Tags: nsis

## Short story

Hi all,

Is there a way to travel recursively a directory with NSIS in compilation time?

Thanks

---

## Long story

Hi all,

I'm trying to create an installer with NSIS for a Software I'm developing. The build system we have setup creates a folder with everything you need to run that Software on Windows (dlls, exes, images, libraries, examples, etc). That folder has +400 files and folders. With HM NIS Edit it was possible to generate the sequence of "File" and "SetOutPath" required to install all the content, but is just huge, ugly and if some files are added or removed then we have to change the script manually.

So... we removed the generated sequence of "File" and "SetOutPath" and just added:

```
File /r "C:\path\to\output\dir"
```

It works great... but now we have a problem with the uninstaller, because we can't do this:

```
RMDir /r $INSTDIR
```

Because is dangerous (as stated here: http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Docs/Chapter4.html#4.9.1.8).

So, we tried to implement the recommendation given there: http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Uninstall_only_installed_files

That solution creates a log on where NSIS writes all the "File" and "SetOutPath" operations made, so it could fallback (remove) on uninstallation. The problem is that the included macros don't support the recursive option of "File".

I've tried to implement a recursive version, by recursively walking on the folder, but I think I'm doing it wrong (well, I'm pretty sure :P):

```
!include "RecFind.nsh"

Section "Principal" SEC01
  ${SetOutPath} "$INSTDIR"
  SetOverwrite try

  ${RecFindOpen} "..\executable" $R0 $R1
   DetailPrint "Looking into directory: $R0"
   ${SetOutPath} "$R0"
  ${RecFindFirst}
   DetailPrint "Looking file: $R0\$R1"
   ${File} "$R0" "$R1"
  ${RecFindNext}
  ${RecFindClose}
```

Using this http://nsis.sourceforge.net/RecFind:_Recursive_FindFirst,_FindNext,_FindClose
But I think that only work in installation time.

The solution I've found until now is to create the installer script with a NSIS file used as a template (with some placeholder token for the "File" and "SetOutPath" list), a Python script that walks on the output directory and creates the sequence of "File" and "SetOutPath" required and then writes the final NSIS script... but I really don't like it :S

So my question is:

Is there a way to travel recursively a directory with NSIS in compilation time?

(Or, how can I achieve this with NSIS only?).

Thanks in advance.

Kind regards

Answer (score 3):

```
!ifdef GENFILELIST
outfile "${GENFILELIST}.exe"
requestexecutionlevel user
silentinstall silent
Var ins
Var uns
Function ProcessDir
Pop $R1 ;reldir
Pop $R0 ;absdir
Push $0
Push $1
FileWrite $ins 'Push $$Outdir$\n'
FileWrite $ins 'SetOutPath "$$instdir\$R1"$\n'
FindFirst $0 $1 "$R0\*"
loop:
    StrCmp "" $1  done
    StrCmp "." $1 next
    StrCmp ".." $1 next
    IfFileExists "$R0\$1\*.*" 0 processfile
        Push $R0
        Push $R1
        Push "$R0\$1"
        Push "$R1$1\"
        call ProcessDir
        Pop $R1
        Pop $R0
        goto next
processfile:
    FileWrite $ins 'File "${SRCDIR}\$R1$1"$\n'
    FileWrite $uns 'Delete "$$instdir\$R1$1"$\n'
next:
    FindNext $0 $1
    Goto loop
done:
FindClose $0
FileWrite $uns 'RMDir "$$instdir\$R1"$\n'
FileWrite $ins 'Pop $$Outdir$\n'
Pop $1
Pop $0
FunctionEnd
section
FileOpen $ins "${GENFILELIST}ins" w
FileOpen $uns "${GENFILELIST}uns" w
Push "${SRCDIR}"
Push ""
call ProcessDir
sectionend
!else
!tempfile FILELIST
!system '"${NSISDIR}\makensis" -NOCD "-DGENFILELIST=${FILELIST}" "-DSRCDIR=.\myfiles" "${__FILE__}"' = 0
!system '"${FILELIST}.exe"' = 0
!delfile "${FILELIST}"
!delfile "${FILELIST}.exe"

### Main script starts here ###

outfile test.exe

page directory
page instfiles

section
SetOutPath $instdir
WriteUninstaller "$instdir\uninst.exe"
!include "${FILELIST}ins"
!delfile "${FILELIST}ins"
sectionend

section uninstall
!include "${FILELIST}uns"
!delfile "${FILELIST}uns"
Delete "$instdir\uninst.exe"
RMDir "$instdir"
sectionend

!endif
```

This uses !system to generate a silent installer and when this silent installer is executed it generates text files with File and Delete commands, the real installer script !include's these to perform the install/uninstall commands.

You could use !system to execute anything, a batch file, windows scripting host, python etc.

Answer (score 0):

You were on the right track.

Use this set of scripts instead.

http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Advanced_Uninstall_Log_NSIS_Header

It allows you to use the recursive functionality of the 'File' function, and it makes an uninstall log for you.